# convert a for loop into a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to change a for loop into a while loop for this function:

```
def sumIt():
    A=1
    number=int(input('Enter a number(integer):'))
    total=0.0
    for counter in range(number):
        total+=A
        A+=1
    print('The sum from 1 to the number is:',total)
    averageIt(total,number)

#average sum and number
def averageIt(total,number):
    print('The average of the sum and the number is:',(total+number)/2)

sumIt()
```

would I just say:

```
while number>1:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increment the `counter` variable manually:

```
counter = 0
while counter < number:
    total += A
    A += 1
    counter += 1
```

or you could decrement the `counter` starting at `number`:

```
counter = number
while counter:
    total += A
    A += 1
    counter -= 1
```

where we use the fact that any non-zero number is True in a boolean context; the `while` loop will end once `counter` reaches `0`.

You use `counter` instead of `number` here because you still need to use `number` later on for the `averageIt()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can by creating the counter yourself:

```
number=int(input('Enter a number(integer):'))
total = 0.0
counter = 0
while counter < number:
    total += A
    A += 1
    counter += 17
```

The `for` block is still the more Pythonic and readable way however. Also try to avoid to cast the result of an user input without verification/`try` block: if he entered 'abc', your code will raise the exception `ValueError`, since it's impossible to convert abc into an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Why even use a loop at all?

Instead of

```
for counter in range(number):
        total+=A
        A+=1
```

Just use

```
total += (number*(number+1) / 2) - (A*(A-1)/2) # account for different starting values of A
A += number
```

Comment: well... If you want to make the OP code more beautiful, just summarize with `sum(range(number))` but I think the OP wants to play with loops just for training.