# Converting a nested for loop to a nested while loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
my_data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
index = 0
for item in my_data:
    k = 0
    for i in range(2, item+1):
        if (i % 2 == 0):
            k += 1
    my_data[index] = k
    index += 1
print(my_data)
```

The above code takes all the elements of the given list and divides them by 2, and it works all fine, however I was trying to convert it into while loop for sake of practice,but for some reason I am getting no error, but the code keeps running and I had to force stop it.

```
i = 0
while i < len(my_data):
    j = 2
    while j < i+1:
        if j % 2 == 0:
            j += 1
    my_data[i] = j
    i += 1
print my_data
```

And here is the method I have tried to implement which seems to not work as far as I am concerned. If someone could clarify it for me I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22205790/convert-a-for-loop-into-a-while-loop).

Comment: `my_data=[ i//2 for i in my_data]` why use all this complicated logic?

Comment: @AlbinPaul Because I am not allowed to use division, otherwise it would have been really easy haha :S

Comment: @Unix How about rightshift operator ?

Comment: @AlbinPaul The thing is, I have to convert this code into MIPS 32, its harder to use for loops in MIPS, so that's why I wanted to go with while loops, also I don't know how would I convert leftshift operator into MIPS, any tips would be welcomed

Comment: @Unix actually its shift right operator for dividing by 2 . And here is the [link](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/assemblytutorial/Chapter-12/ass12_6.html) for it

Comment: @AlbinPaul Thanks man, I will start studying about it and hopefully get an idea around it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your second while loop moves forward only if j is pair and if j is not (since j increase only by 1) the while loop will loop for ever.
you've made a little mistake by replacing k with j, and you should continue using k

```
i = 0
while i < len(my_data):
    j = 2
    k = 0
    while j < i+1:
        if j % 2 == 0:
            k+=1
        j += 1
    my_data[i] = k
    i += 1
print my_data
```

Answer (score 1):

At line 5:

```
if j % 2 == 0:
```

When `i==3` and `j==3`, the if statement is ignored. `j` can't be increased. It will be looped forever, since the stop criterion is `j<i+1`
Just add an `else` statement to handle that case

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot, but what do you recommend me to add at else, I will give you the correct answer now. @enamoria

Comment: at else add j += 1 i think

Comment: @Unix I don't actually understand your code. I wonder why you need 2 nested `for` to divide a list by 2? All you need is a single `for`, or a more pythonic way, using `list comprehension`: `[x/2 for x in my_data]`

Comment: @enamoria Check the above comments that I had with AlbinPaul and you will understand why I went this way

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to divide each item of a list using while you also try this way.

```
my_data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42]
index = 0
while len(my_data) > index:
    my_data[index] = int(my_data[index]/2)
    index +=1

print(my_data)
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, however I am not allowed to use division, thus I cannot implement this!